# Where do you put selected states on Raphael.js map?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, raphael

Is anyone familiar with Raphael.js?

This site uses PHP & Wordpress and creted these "interactive" maps with Raphael.js. The two maps are on two different WP Post pages.

[image]

[image]

Struggling to understand where in the code, the selected states are set to have default blue or gold color.  Are both maps created with in this one file?

```html
(function($, document, window, Raphael, undefined) {
  // jQuery Plugin Factory
  function jQueryPluginFactory( $, name, methods, getters ){
    getters = getters instanceof Array ? getters : [];
    var getters_obj = {};
    for(var i=0; i<getters.length; i++){
      getters_obj[getters[i]] = true;
    }
  
    
    // Create the object
    var Plugin = function(element){
      this.element = element;
    };
    Plugin.prototype = methods;
    
    // Assign the plugin
    $.fn[name] = function(){
      var args = arguments;
      var returnValue = this;
      
      this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var plugin = $this.data('plugin-'+name);
        // Init the plugin if first time
        if( !plugin ){
          plugin = new Plugin($this);
          $this.data('plugin-'+name, plugin);
          if(plugin._init){
            plugin._init.apply(plugin, args);
          }
          
        // call a method
        } else if(typeof args[0] == 'string' && args[0].charAt(0) != '_' && typeof plugin[args[0]] == 'function'){
          var methodArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1);
          var r = plugin[args[0]].apply(plugin, methodArgs);
          // set the return value if method is a getter
          if( args[0] in getters_obj ){
            returnValue = r;
          }
        }
        
      });
      
      return returnValue; // returning the jQuery object
    };
  };
  
  
  // Some constants
  var WIDTH = 930,
      HEIGHT = 630,
      LABELS_WIDTH = 70;
  
  // Default options
  var defaults = {
    // The styles for the state
    'stateStyles': {
      fill: "#E7E8E8",
      stroke: "#ADCEE9",
      "stroke-width": 1,
      "stroke-linejoin": "round",
      scale: [1, 1]
    },
    
    // The styles for the hover
    'stateHoverStyles': {
      fill: "#17427A",
      stroke: "#F89B25",
      scale: [1.1, 1.1]
    },
    
    // The time for the animation, set to false to remove the animation
    'stateHoverAnimation': 500,
    
    // State specific styles. 'ST': {}
    'stateSpecificStyles': {},
    
    // State specific hover styles
    'stateSpecificHoverStyles': {},
    
    
    // Events
    'click': null,
    
    'mouseover': null,
    
    'mouseout': null,
    
    'clickState': {},
    
    'mouseoverState': {},
    
    'mouseoutState': {},
    
    
    // Labels
    'showLabels' : true,
    
    'labelWidth': 20,
    
    'labelHeight': 15,
    
    'labelGap' : 6,
    
    'labelRadius' : 3,
    
    'labelBackingStyles': {
      fill: "#F89B25",
      stroke: "#666",
      "stroke-width": 1,
      "stroke-linejoin": "round",
      scale: [1, 1]
    },
    
    // The styles for the hover
    'labelBackingHoverStyles': {
      fill: "#17427A",
      stroke: "#F89B25"
    },
    
    'stateSpecificLabelBackingStyles': {},
    
    'stateSpecificLabelBackingHoverStyles': {},
    
    'labelTextStyles': {
      fill: "#fff",
      'stroke': 'none',
      'font-weight': 300,
      'stroke-width': 0,
      'font-size': '10px'
    },
    
    // The styles for the hover
    'labelTextHoverStyles': {},
    
    'stateSpecificLabelTextStyles': {},
    
    'stateSpecificLabelTextHoverStyles': {}
  };
  
  
  // Methods
  var methods = {
    /**
     * The init function
     */
    _init: function(options) {
      // Save the options
      this.options = {};
      $.extend(this.options, defaults, options);
      
      // Save the width and height;
      var width = this.element.width();
      var height = this.element.height();
      
      // Calculate the width and height to match the container while keeping the labels at a fixed size
      var xscale = this.element.width()/WIDTH;
      var yscale = this.element.height()/HEIGHT;
      this.scale = Math.min(xscale, yscale);
      this.labelAreaWidth = Math.ceil(LABELS_WIDTH/this.scale); // The actual width with the labels reversed scaled
      
      var paperWidthWithLabels = WIDTH + Math.max(0, this.labelAreaWidth - LABELS_WIDTH);
      // Create the Raphael instances
      this.paper = Raphael(this.element.get(0), paperWidthWithLabels, HEIGHT);//this.element.width(), this.element.height());
      
      // Scale to fit
      this.paper.setSize(width, height);
      this.paper.setViewBox(0, 0, paperWidthWithLabels, HEIGHT, false);
      
      // Keep track of all the states
      this.stateHitAreas = {}; // transparent for the hit area
      this.stateShapes = {}; // for the visual shape
      this.topShape = null;
      
      // create all the states
      this._initCreateStates();
      
      // create the labels for the smaller states
      this.labelShapes = {};
      this.labelTexts = {};
      this.labelHitAreas = {};
      if(this.options.showLabels) {
        this._initCreateLabels();
      }
      
      // Add the 
    },
    
    /**
     * Create the state objects
     */
    _initCreateStates: function() {
      // TODO: Dynamic attrs
      var attr = this.options.stateStyles;
      var R = this.paper; // shorter name for usage here
      
      // The coords for each state
      var paths = {
        HI: "M 233.08751,519.30948 L 235.02744,515.75293 L 237.2907,515.42961 L 237.61402,516.23791 L 235.51242,519.30948 z M 243.27217,515.59127 L 249.4153,518.17784 L 251.51689,517.85452 L 253.1335,513.97465 L 252.48686,510.57977 L 248.28366,510.09479 L 244.24213,511.87306 z M 273.9878,525.61427 L 277.706,531.11074 L 280.13092,530.78742 L 281.26255,530.30244 L 282.7175,531.59573 L 286.43571,531.43407 L 287.40568,529.97912 L 284.49577,528.20085 L 282.55584,524.48263 L 280.45424,520.92609 L 274.63444,523.83599 z M 294.19545,534.50564 L 295.48874,532.5657 L 300.17691,533.53566 L 300.82356,533.05068 L 306.96668,533.69732 L 306.64336,534.99062 L 304.05678,536.44556 L 299.69193,536.12224 z M 299.53027,539.67879 L 301.47021,543.55866 L 304.54176,542.42703 L 304.86509,540.81041 L 303.24848,538.70882 L 299.53027,538.3855 z M 306.4817,538.54716 L 308.74496,535.63726 L 313.43313,538.06218 L 317.79798,539.19381 L 322.16284,541.94205 L 322.16284,543.88198 L 318.6063,545.66026 L 313.75645,546.63022 L 311.33154,545.17527 z M 323.13281,554.06663 L 324.74942,552.77335 L 328.14431,554.38997 L 335.74238,557.94651 L 339.13727,560.0481 L 340.75387,562.47302 L 342.69381,566.83787 L 346.73534,569.42445 L 346.41202,570.71775 L 342.53215,573.95097 L 338.32896,575.40592 L 336.87401,574.75928 L 333.80244,576.53754 L 331.37753,579.77077 L 329.11427,582.68067 L 327.33599,582.51901 L 323.77945,579.93243 L 323.45613,575.40592 L 324.10277,572.981 L 322.48616,567.32286 L 320.38456,565.54458 L 320.2229,562.958 L 322.48616,561.98804 L 324.58776,558.91648 L 325.07274,557.94651 L 323.45613,556.16823 z",
       
       ...
       
        DC: "M 801.75695,253.84384 L 800.67992,252.20717 L 799.66604,251.36463 L 800.7653,249.74841 L 802.99814,251.25941 z"
      
      }
      
      // Create the actual objects
      var stateAttr = {};
      for(var state in paths) {
        stateAttr = {};
        if(this.options.stateSpecificStyles[state]) {
          $.extend(stateAttr, attr, this.options.stateSpecificStyles[state]);
        } else {
          stateAttr = attr;
        }
        this.stateShapes[state] = R.path(paths[state]).attr(stateAttr);
        this.topShape = this.stateShapes[state];
        
        this.stateHitAreas[state] = R.path(paths[state]).attr({fill: "#000",
      "stroke-width": 0, "opacity" : 0.0, 'cursor': 'pointer'});
        this.stateHitAreas[state].node.dataState = state;
      }
      
      // Bind events
      this._onClickProxy = $.proxy(this, '_onClick');
      this._onMouseOverProxy = $.proxy(this, '_onMouseOver'),
      this._onMouseOutProxy = $.proxy(this, '_onMouseOut');
        
      for(var state in this.stateHitAreas) {
        this.stateHitAreas[state].toFront();
        $(this.stateHitAreas[state].node).bind('mouseout', this._onMouseOutProxy);
        $(this.stateHitAreas[state].node).bind('click', this._onClickProxy);
        $(this.stateHitAreas[state].node).bind('mouseover', this._onMouseOverProxy);
        
      }
    },
    
    
    
    /**
     * Create the labels
     */
    _initCreateLabels: function() {
      var R = this.paper; // shorter name for usage here
      var neStates = ['CA', 'AL', 'AR','AZ', 'CO', 'FL', 'GA', 'IL', 'IN', 'LA', 'MI', 'MS', 'MO', 'NC' , 'NV', 'NY', 'OR', 'PA', 'TN', 'TX', 'WI'];
      
      // calculate the values for placing items
      var neBoxX = 860;
      var neBoxY = 220;
      var oWidth = this.options.labelWidth;
      var oHeight = this.options.labelHeight;
      var oGap = this.options.labelGap;
      var oRadius = this.options.labelRadius;
      
      var shapeWidth = oWidth/this.scale;
      var shapeHeight = oHeight/this.scale;
      
      var colWidth = (oWidth+oGap)/this.scale;
      var downBy = (oHeight+oGap)/this.scale*0.5;
      
      var shapeRadius = oRadius/this.scale;
      
      // Styling information
      var backingAttr = this.options.labelBackingStyles;
      var textAttr = this.options.labelTextStyles;
      var stateAttr = {};
      
      // NE States
      for(var i=0, x, y, state; i<neStates.length; ++i) {
        state = neStates[i];
        
        // position
        x = ((i+1)%2) * colWidth + neBoxX;
        y = i*downBy + neBoxY;
        
        // attributes for styling the backing
        stateAttr = {};
        if(this.options.stateSpecificLabelBackingStyles[state]) {
          $.extend(stateAttr, backingAttr, this.options.stateSpecificLabelBackingStyles[state]);
        } else {
          stateAttr = backingAttr;
        }
        
        // add the backing
        this.labelShapes[state] = R.rect(x, y, shapeWidth, shapeHeight, shapeRadius).attr(stateAttr);
        
        // attributes for styling the text
        stateAttr = {};
        if(this.options.stateSpecificLabelTextStyles[state]) {
          $.extend(stateAttr, textAttr, this.options.stateSpecificLabelTextStyles[state]);
        } else {
          $.extend(stateAttr, textAttr);
        }
        
        // adjust font-size
        if(stateAttr['font-size']) {
          stateAttr['font-size'] = (parseInt(stateAttr['font-size'])/this.scale) + 'px';
        }
        
        // add the text
        this.labelTexts[state] = R.text(x+(shapeWidth/2), y+(shapeHeight/2), state).attr(stateAttr);
        
        // Create the hit areas
        this.labelHitAreas[state] = R.rect(x, y, shapeWidth, shapeHeight, shapeRadius).attr({
          fill: "#F89B25",
          "stroke-width": 0, 
          "opacity" : 0.0, 
          'cursor': 'pointer'
        });
        this.labelHitAreas[state].node.dataState = state;
      }
      
      
      
      // Bind events
      for(var state in this.labelHitAreas) {
        this.labelHitAreas[state].toFront();
        $(this.labelHitAreas[state].node).bind('mouseout', this._onMouseOutProxy);
        $(this.labelHitAreas[state].node).bind('click', this._onClickProxy);
        $(this.labelHitAreas[state].node).bind('mouseover', this._onMouseOverProxy);
      }
    },
    
    
    
    /**
     * Get the state Raphael object
     */
    _getStateFromEvent: function(event) {
      // first get the state name
      var stateName = (event.target && event.target.dataState) || (event.dataState);
      return this._getState(stateName);
    },
    
    
    /**
     *
     */
    _getState: function(stateName) {
      var stateShape = this.stateShapes[stateName];
      var stateHitArea = this.stateHitAreas[stateName];
      var labelBacking = this.labelShapes[stateName];
      var labelText = this.labelTexts[stateName];
      var labelHitArea = this.labelHitAreas[stateName]
      
      return {
        shape: stateShape, 
        hitArea: stateHitArea, 
        name: stateName, 
        labelBacking: labelBacking, 
        labelText: labelText, 
        labelHitArea: labelHitArea
      };
    },
```

Comment: Did you try to read that code ? Did you see the values in the format `#<something>` (for example `#E7E8E8`) ? did you try to play with it ?

Comment: I mean I can see where the fill is happening to the State variables in the path, but I don't see where the specific colored states are being set in the first place. Also this code looks like its only for the blue map, but can't find any other code for a gold map.